# C++ logging: __VA_ARGS__ causes double promotion [-Wdouble-promotion]

Tags: c++, c, logging, c-preprocessor

I would like to turn on -Wdouble-promotion flag on my embedded project to avoid any accidental use of doubles. It was very useful however I can't fix my logger component because it uses `__VA_ARGS__`:

```
void log( const LogLevel _level, const char* const _file, const int _line, const char* const _format, ... )
{
    va_list args;
    va_start( args, _format );
    Com< ILogger >()->Log( _level, _file, _line, _format, args );
    va_end(args);
}
#define LOG_CRITICAL(...) log(LogLevel_Critical, __FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
```

When I use `stdarg.h` or `__VA_ARGS__` my floats are promoted into doubles (it is the standard behavior)...

```
base/logger.h, line 35, column 76:  warning: implicit conversion from ‘float’ to ‘double’ when passing argument to function [-Wdouble-promotion]
#define LOG_WARN(...) log(LogLevel_Warning, __FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
                                                                           ^
base/ntp.cpp, line 91, column 6:  note: in expansion of macro ‘LOG_WARN’
LOG_WARN("System time is stepped by NTP daemon! (%f sec)", offset);
^~~~~~~~
```

It is an unfortunate situation, however it would be a really hard work to modify my logger component not to use printf in the background so I decided to suppress this error in this header:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdouble-promotion"
//(...) my logger component
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

But it was unsuccessful because the warning is triggered when the compiler elaborates the `#define LOG_CRITICAL(...) log(LogLevel_Critical, __FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)` macro in the caller file.

How can I suppress the double-promotion warning of the variadic macro? GCC specific solutions are OK too.

**Update 1:**

I have checked alk's solution:

```
#define LOG_CRITICAL(...) \
_Pragma( "GCC diagnostic push" ) \
_Pragma( "GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Wdouble-promotion\"" ) \
log(LogLevel_Critical, __FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__) \
_Pragma( "GCC diagnostic pop" )
```

After the modification there are many errors:

```
core/app_health.cpp, line 118, column 1:  error: ‘#pragma’ is not allowed here
LOG_ERROR("[Main]");
```

I think this kind of pragma isn't allowed inside functions...

Comment: And you don't want to turn off the warning for the rest of the project, only for this specific call?

Comment: I don't want to turn it off completely, in any other cases the flag is very useful.

Comment: Why do you add the C tag while your code is C++?

Comment: @Gerhardh: It is a preprocessor-related problem, it exists in C too.

Comment: What is forcing you disable the flag for the entire project?

Comment: I have already disabled the flag (`#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdouble-promotion"`) in the logger source files. The problem is the macro inside the logger's header: when the compiler elaborates the macro it raises a warning in the caller's source file, but in that file the double promotion isn't suppressed.

Comment: I see. Casting to double will have to be done.